# validating a dropdown option (menu)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Working on a small website that contains a form, one of the options is a drop-down option(menu) that look like this

adduser.html

```
<label for="username">Username: <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="" /><br /> 
<select name="level">
  <option value="1">Select Level...</option>
  <option value="2">Boss</option>
  <option value="3">Employee</option>
</select><br />
<label for="password">Password: <input type="text" id="password" name="password" value="" /><br />
```

And I'm doing this to validate if not option is selected

uservalidation.php

```
if(empty($_POST['username']))
{
  die("Enter a username<br><a href='adduser.php'>back</a>");
}

if(empty($_POST['password']))
{
  die("Enter a password<br><a href='adduser.php'>back</a>");
}

if(isset($_POST['level']) && ($_POST['level'] == '1'))
{
  die("Select level<br><a href='adduser.php'>back</a>");
}
```

But this is not working any idea why, or how to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: it seems good, try to var_dump($_POST) to see exactly what you have inside

Comment: You included the tag javascript.....have you tried client-side validation, such as function which checks if option "1" was selected before the form is submitted?

Comment: @ThomasP1988 I try adding the var_dump, but when I click submit nothing happen is like is not detecting that value is 1

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob yeah I already did that, but I also have to do it on the serve site

Comment: Related to the point made by @ThomasP1988, Have you tried $POST['level'] == 1 in case the option value is being treated by php as a number instead of a string?

Comment: did you install apache, php ? wamp, lamp or xamp ?

Comment: @ThomasP1988  yeah I don't i don have a ny problem with that

Comment: What is `not working`... what actually happens? nothing? Also can you post your full `form` with `form` tags?

Comment: you did or not ? i don't understand. Show us your whole code please (HTML and PHP)

Comment: @imbondbaby well what im trying to do is to force the user to select one of the option, boss or employee and if the leave the opcion empty(select level)

Comment: put whole html please, you don't have <?php ?> in your php

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do... please post your COMPLETE HTML

Comment: @imbondbaby thats all the html

Comment: @ThomasP1988 I have the php tag, the others validation are working fine but just the level one not

Comment: @Alberto Please add `var_dump($_POST);` _before_ your validation and paste the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `form` tags around the HTML and make sure you use `method="post"` in the `form` tag in order for your `POST` request to work in `PHP`.

The `action` attribute of the `form` tag just specifies the URL that the form will submit the data to.

**Try this:**

```
<form action="#" method="post">
<label for="username">Username: <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="" /><br /> 
<select name="level">
  <option value="1">Select Level...</option>
  <option value="2">Boss</option>
  <option value="3">Employee</option>
</select><br />
<label for="password">Password: <input type="text" id="password" name="password" value="" /><br />
<input type="submit">
</form>
<?
if(isset($_POST['level']) && ($_POST['level'] == '1'))
{
  die("Select level<br><a href='adduser.php'>back</a>");
}
?>
```

**UPDATE**

As mentioned in the comments, I added an `isset($_POST)` check in there to avoid `Undefined index`.

Comment: You should add an `isset($_POST['level'])` check in there also, to avoid `Undefined index`.

Comment: @ChrisMagnussen thank you for that! Updated it with credits ofcourse

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you're validating whether or not the form was posted.

```
if(isset($_POST['level']) && ($_POST['level'] == '1'))
{
  die("Select level<br><a href='adduser.php'>back</a>");
}
```

Comment: @Alberto Try var_dump($_POST) before your if statement and paste the result.